# JNI: Program shows "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: client.dll: The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: java, c++

I have a java program which requires a library compiled in C++. For this I generated the JNI header files and then I compiled my c++ app library into .dll using JNI. Currently, I am having a problem where after the linkage is completed, I am not able to run my java program. It shows the following error below:

```
public app.IncClientTester(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: IncClient.dll: The specified 
procedure could not be found
```

This is my Java code:

```
public class IncClientTester extends Tester {
public IncClientTester(String h, String u, String p) {
    super(h, u, p);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public native boolean getComponentStatus(int status, int ver);

public native boolean getDeviceThresholdHit();

static {
    System.loadLibrary("IncClient");
}
}
```

This is my C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_app_IncClientTester_getComponentStatus (JNIEnv*, jobject, jint applstat, jint applversion) { 
     // some code in here
     return status // boolean
}
```

This is my C++ Cmakelist.txt:

```
project(Inc)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0081 NEW)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -std=c++0x")


#find_package(vsomeip 2.14.16 REQUIRED)

# Boost
find_package( Boost 1.59 COMPONENTS system thread log REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

if(Boost_FOUND)
  if(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR)
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIR not empty using it: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR}" )
  else()
    if(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR)
      MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost_LIBRARY_DIR empty but BOOST_LIBRARYDIR is set setting Boost_LIBRARY_DIR to: ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR}" )
      set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
    endif()
  endif()
else()
  MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost was not found!")
endif() 

message(STATUS "vsomeip is found, version:"${vsomeip_VERSION}) 

include_directories(
    src-gen
    capicxx-core-runtime-3.2.0/include
    capicxx-someip-runtime-3.2.0/include
    vsomeip/interface
    "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261/include"
    "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261/include/win32"
)
link_directories(
    capicxx-core-runtime-3.2.0/build/Debug
    capicxx-someip-runtime-3.2.0/build/Debug
    vsomeip/build/Debug
    #/usr/lib
)

# Voltage
add_library(IncClient SHARED
    src/IncClient.cpp
    src-gen/v1/commonapi/IncSomeIPProxy.cpp
    src-gen/v1/commonapi/IncSomeIPDeployment.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(IncClient CommonAPI CommonAPI-SomeIP vsomeip3)
```

Can someone help me to guide me on how to fix this issue.

Comment: *This is my C++ code:* -- That code is not C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for notifying it. I have updated my question.

Comment: If that's really your C++ code, then you have invoked undefined behavior by not returning a value from that function that's supposed to return a `jboolean`.  The function is supposed to return a `jboolean`, but you returned nothing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have edited my question, in my real code, I have returned the boolean status. The weird part is I did use the same method in my previous implementation everything was working fine. But now, I try to copy the same flow for my current implementation, I am getting the error as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: @RaajLokanathan did you also define `getDeviceThresholdHit` in your c++?

Comment: Well either your original code really was not "working fine" and now the bug has been exposed, or you shouldn't just copy code from somewhere else and hope it works for a different program and situation.

Comment: @fukanchik Yes i did. But now, both this methods I am not able to test in my java program even though it has been implemented.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would like to double confirm the steps for JNI. I am following this tutorial now. I did my implementation based on the link below:

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

Comment: Maybe you forgot to specify `extern "C"`?

Comment: @heapunderrun the extern "C" is added automatically in the generated .h file when i run the command `javac -cp ..\..\lib\a.jar -h . IncClientTester.java Tester.java`